# Window closes after going to another window then coming back

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qpushbutton

I am trying to go from window to window and back and forward.

I have tried using while True: and cannot seem to get it to work. It just prints HOME a million times and crashes the window.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import IMAGE_rc
import sys
from GUIWINDOW1 import *
import time


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
        def setup(self, MainWindow):
            MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
            MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
            MainWindow.resize(800, 480)
            sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
            sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
            sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
            sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
            MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
            MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 480))
            MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 480))
            MainWindow.setMouseTracking(False)
            MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 255, 127);")
            MainWindow.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)
            MainWindow.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Rounded)
            self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
            self.centralwidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 480))
            self.centralwidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 480))
            self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
            self.TOUCH1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.TOUCH1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 10, 662, 200))
            self.TOUCH1.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(/PROGRAMMING/QT DESIGNER/GUIIMAGES/LOGO.png);")
            self.TOUCH1.setText("")
            self.TOUCH1.setObjectName("TOUCH1")
            self.TOUCH2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.TOUCH2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 220, 360, 200))
            self.TOUCH2.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(/PROGRAMMING/QT DESIGNER/GUIIMAGES/1200px-Florida_Atlantic_Owls_logo.svg.png);\n"
    "background-color: rgb(170, 255, 127);")
            self.TOUCH2.setText("")
            self.TOUCH2.setObjectName("TOUCH2")
            self.TOUCH4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.TOUCH4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 801, 481))
            self.TOUCH4.setStyleSheet("")
            self.TOUCH4.setObjectName("TOUCH4")
            self.TOUCH3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.TOUCH3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 430, 611, 41))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setPointSize(16)
            self.TOUCH3.setFont(font)
            self.TOUCH3.setStyleSheet("")
            self.TOUCH3.setObjectName("TOUCH3")
            self.TOUCH4.raise_()
            self.TOUCH1.raise_()
            self.TOUCH2.raise_()
            self.TOUCH3.raise_()
            MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

            self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
            self.TOUCH1.clicked.connect(self.BEGIN)
            self.TOUCH2.clicked.connect(self.BEGIN)
            self.TOUCH3.clicked.connect(self.BEGIN)
            self.TOUCH4.clicked.connect(self.BEGIN)

        def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
            self.TOUCH4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
            self.TOUCH3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TAP ANYWHERE TO BEGIN"))

        def BEGIN(self):
            print("HOME")
            self.WINDOW1=QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
            self.ui = Ui_WINDOW1()
            self.ui.setup(self.WINDOW1)
            self.WINDOW1.showFullScreen()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setup(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.showFullScreen()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Window closes when i go back and forward from MainWindow to WINDOW1 and try to go back to WINDOW1

Comment: How are you getting back to MainWindow from WINDOW1?

Comment: Using the "BACK1" button. I can get back to MainWindow but then when I try to click the MainWindow again it closes

Comment: The BACK1 Button is in the other Script "WINDOW1"

Comment: I understand you have a back-button in the other widget, but what is the actual code in `WINDOW1` you use to get back to the main window.